# Variables causing parse error in php class definition

Tags: php, variables

Why is this causing a parse error? If I swap out the variables for integers it works fine. I can only assume that the parser is unable to resolve the variables inside the string, but I can't understand why.

```
    private $last_fetch=array(); // the content of the last database query
    private $last_thread_id=0; // the id of the last thread of the previous fetch
    private $threads_max_fetch=20; // max number of threads to fetch from the database

    private $q="SELECT DISTINCT mt.* 
        FROM message_thread mt
        INNER JOIN message m
        ON mt.thread_id=m.thread.id
        WHERE mt.thread_id < $this->last_thread_id
        ORDER BY m.message_datetime
        LIMIT $this->threads_max_fetch";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) about the declaration of class properties:

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

So you cannot use variables in your declaration / intitialization at all.

Comment: [This is quite correct](http://ideone.com/X8SpR9), despite the fact that this _could_ quite easily be made allowed in this case for a variety of reasons. The manual is actually a little ambiguous because the string's value _is_ completely known at compile-time, but regardless the interpreter makes no distinction. As such, this isn't a complete answer, but it is still correct.